# How to create a box plot with javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, boxplot

I need to make a box plot in javafx without using extensions. I managed to create the box but I can't put it inside the axes (I tried with all types of Pane layouts).

Does anyone know how this type of graph can be created using only this library and if so how can I put my box inside the axes?

Comment: Also, have a look at [chartfx](https://github.com/fair-acc/chart-fx). [Example](https://github.com/fair-acc/chart-fx/blob/main/docs/pics/FinancialAdvancedCandlestickSample.png)

Comment: *”I managed to create the box but I cannot put it inside the axes”*. So your specific question appears to be about how to combine your implementation of the box with your implementation of the axes? It’s basically impossible for anyone to really answer that as we don’t know how you are implementing either of those, or what goes wrong when you try. Create and post a [mre] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use [JFreeChartFX](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart-fx) to [create a box plot](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBoxAndWhiskerDemo.htm).

But if you must use JavaFX charts, then perhaps you could study and adapt [this candlestick chart](https://github.com/lusalome/javafx-ensemble/blob/master/src/main/java/ensemble/samples/charts/custom/AdvCandleStickChartSample.java).